# Django 1.11.2 serializer nested json array

Tags: django, serialization

I am new to both Python and Django and I would appreciate some guidance with a problem I'm having with Django REST, nested JSON and the serializer.

I wish to post:

```
{ "Server": [
    {
    "serverSerialNumber": "0000",
    "serverUniqueKey": "2222"
    },
    {
    "serverSerialNumber": "0001",
    "serverUniqueKey": "2223"
    }
]
}
```

This is my serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Api

class ApiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = Api
        fields = ('id', 'serverSerialNumber', 'serverUniqueKey', 'date_created', 'date_modified')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified')
        depth = 1
```

I simply receive the following back:

```
{
    "serverSerialNumber": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

So I am not understanding how to use 'depth' or I'm doing something silly.

Adding View per request:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import ApiSerializer
from .models import Api

class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """This class defines the create behavior of our rest api."""
    queryset = Api.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApiSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new item."""
        serializer.save()
```

Ok, so I've stumbled through some documentation and had another bash at this.
Still not working but the code seems to make more sense, here is the new code and error:

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Blade, Servers

class BladeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Blade
        fields = ('id', 'serverSerialNumber', 'serverUniqueKey', 'date_created', 'date_modified')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified')

class ServersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Server = BladeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Servers
        fields = ['Server']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        servers_data = validated_data.pop('Server')
        srv = Servers.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for server_data in servers_data:
            Blade.objects.create(srv=srv, **server_data)
        return srv
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from api.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import BladeSerializer, ServersSerializer
from .models import Blade, Servers

class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Servers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServersSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from inventory.models import Server

class Blade(models.Model):
    instanceId = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)
    chassisUniqueKey = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)
    serverUniqueKey = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)
    serverSerialNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return "{}".format(self.name)

class Servers(models.Model):

    Servers = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
            """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
            return "{}".format(self.name)
```

The error

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `Server` on serializer `ServersSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Servers` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Servers' object has no attribute 'Server'.

Comment: I updated the post to make it make more sense.
This is how the data will arrive at my django rest api.

Comment: could you show the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Api.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApiSerializer 

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data) 
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting.
The POST request does not throw an exception but it also does not place data into the table.

Comment: Try overriding the create method in the serializer

Comment: Did you try printing the serializer.data after calling serializer.is_valid()

Comment: Totally reworked the code, still not working but I feel that it's closer